# Spell check in Visualstudio 2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I gone through several things over the internet and I was not able to figure out does visual studio 2008 support the option for spell check like visual studio 2010 does having an option of spell check button in the toolbox...If so can some one suggest me a way that i can make it available for the Email message(I want to use the spell check option to the Email before sending it) ....Is there something to do with the service pack 2 .....

Following is the code for sending an email in my application and I need to spell check the body of the message as that is the only place where we enter the text

```
private void setEmailValues()
    {
        var eml = new EmailInformation
        {
            SendTo = this.ctlDocDelivery.EmailAddresses,
            SendCc = this.ctlDocDelivery.CC,
            SendBcc = this.ctlDocDelivery.BCC,
            Subject = this.ctlDocDelivery.Subject,
            Body = this.ctlDocDelivery.MessageBody,
            SendAsAttachment = (this.ctlDocDelivery.SendAs == DocumentDeliveryControl.SendAsSelections.ATTACHMENT),
            DoNotSend = !this.ctlDocDelivery.ShowEmailPanel
        };

        // Mark as do not send if we're not showing the email panel:
        this.setApproverSecondApproverValues();

        Session[AppConstants.SK_EMAILINFORMATION] = eml;
    }

    private void setApproverSecondApproverValues()
    {
        var acct = (Account) Session[AppConstants.SK_ACTION_ACCOUNT];

        if (ctlDocDelivery.ShowApprovalPanel)
        {
            acct.CurrentRisk.ApprovedById = ctlDocDelivery.ApprovalUnderwriterId;
            acct.CurrentRisk.ApprovedDate = ctlDocDelivery.ApprovalDate;
        }

        if (!this.ctlDocDelivery.ShowSecondApprovalPanel)
            return;

        acct.CurrentRisk.SecondApprovedById = this.ctlDocDelivery.SecondApprovalUnderwriterId;
        acct.CurrentRisk.SecondApprovedDate = this.ctlDocDelivery.SecondApprovalDate;
    }

    private void cleanUpCachedEntities()
    {
        var formSessionKeys = (ArrayList) Session[AppConstants.SK_FORM_SESSION_KEYS];

        foreach (string sessionKey in formSessionKeys)
            Session.Remove(sessionKey);
    }

    private void generatePageScripts()
    {
        if (Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "DocumentDelivery"))
            return;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(2048);

        sb.AppendFormat("function {0}_OnClick() {{" + Environment.NewLine, this.ctlDocDelivery.ChkBoxAllReviewsCompletedClientID);
        sb.AppendLine("    var chkBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.ChkBoxAllReviewsCompletedClientID + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var btnSendForReview = ig_getWebControlById('" + this.btnSendforReview.ClientID + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var btnRelease = ig_getWebControlById('" + this.btnRelease.ClientID + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var gbBxDlvryInfo = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.gbBoxDeliveryInfoClientID + "');");

        sb.AppendLine("    var txtToBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.txtToClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var txtCCBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.txtCCClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var txtBCCBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.txtBCCClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var txtSubBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.txtSubClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var txtBodyBox = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.txtMsgBodyClientId + "');");

        sb.AppendLine("    if (txtToBox !== null) txtToBox.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");
        sb.AppendLine("    if (txtCCBox !== null) txtCCBox.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");
        sb.AppendLine("    if (txtBCCBox !== null) txtBCCBox.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");
        sb.AppendLine("    if (txtSubBox !== null) txtSubBox.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");
        sb.AppendLine("    if (txtBodyBox !== null) txtBodyBox.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");

        sb.AppendLine("    btnSendForReview.setEnabled(!chkBox.checked);");
        sb.AppendLine("    var elemBtnSendForRev = btnSendForReview.getElement();");
        sb.AppendLine("    btnRelease.setEnabled(chkBox.checked);");
        sb.AppendLine("    var elemBtnRel = btnRelease.getElement();");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("    if(btnSendForReview.getEnabled())");
        sb.AppendLine("      elemBtnSendForRev.style.cursor = 'hand';");
        sb.AppendLine("    else");
        sb.AppendLine("      elemBtnSendForRev.style.cursor = 'auto';");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("    var lblNotificationMessage = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.lblNotificationMessageClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    var tblNotificationMessage = document.getElementById('" + this.ctlDocDelivery.tblNotificationMessageClientId + "');");
        sb.AppendLine("    if(btnRelease.getEnabled())");
        sb.AppendLine("    {");

        var acct = (Account) this.Session[AppConstants.SK_ACTION_ACCOUNT];
        var displayNotificationMessage = acct.CurrentRisk
                                             .ValidationResults
                                             .Cast<ValidationResult>()
                                             .Any(validationResult => validationResult.ValidationTypeId == (int) EnumValidationType.NOTIFICATION);

        if (displayNotificationMessage)
            sb.AppendLine("             tblNotificationMessage.style.visibility = 'visible';");

        sb.AppendLine("         elemBtnRel.style.cursor = 'hand';");
        sb.AppendLine("    }");
        sb.AppendLine("    else");
        sb.AppendLine("    {");
        sb.AppendLine("         tblNotificationMessage.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
        sb.AppendLine("         elemBtnRel.style.cursor = 'auto';");
        sb.AppendLine("    }");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("    if(gbBxDlvryInfo !== null) gbBxDlvryInfo.disabled = !chkBox.checked;");
        sb.AppendLine("}");

        var chkAllReviewsCompleted = this.Page.FindControl(this.ctlDocDelivery.ChkBoxAllReviewsCompletedUniqueID) as CheckBox;
        chkAllReviewsCompleted.Attributes["onclick"] = this.ctlDocDelivery.ChkBoxAllReviewsCompletedClientID + "_OnClick();";

        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DocumentDelivery", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: which Email Message you are talking about ? Outlook ?

Comment: @Shyju I am sorry I am not sure of what you were talking about ..I am using this to send an email out to the users with the documents attached to it to the email which we have on file (should be Outlook )

Comment: Are you trying to spellcheck user data, or your own code?

Comment: @jack I am trying to spell check the data which I am sending it to the users(own code)...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand you, who is supposed to use the spellchecker? are you trying to have a client side spellchecker for the end users?

Comment: @Jack thanks for looking in to ..yes I would like to have it on the client side

Comment: Have you tried searching for one? At any rate I don't believe that there is any spellchecker that ships with VS 2008 or 2010.

Comment: @Jack I am sure that there is a plug in available for this in 2010 but when I browsed over the internet I did  not come up with a clear solution for this for 2008

Comment: There are several plugins that enables you to spellcheck your code or comments you can see them at the [visual studio extension gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f[1].Type=SearchText&f[1].Value=spell+checker&f[0].Value=tools&f[0].Type=RootCategory&x=0&y=0), there are also specll checker components which you can easily find if you [search for them](http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+spell+checker&form=MOZSBR&pc=MOZI).